# Java Regex find() method not returning proper value

Tags: java, regex

I've created a regex pattern in Java and, apparently, the matcher class find it into the string, but it is not returning the proper value.

If you see this [image](https://i.ibb.co/3MpDxnv/Java-Reg-Ex-Problem.png), Eclipse is giving me a 'true' value when I execute `m.find()` method, but it's not assigning it properly to `isMatch` variable.

Same occurs when I write "`if (m.find())`, it doesn't go to the inner block.

Code Example:

{

```
    private final static String REGEX_PATTERN_FILE_GROUP = "(\\d{14}_\\d{9}_\\D{3}_\\d{11}_)";

    for (File file: fileList) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN_FILE_GROUP);  
        Matcher m = p.matcher(file.getName());              
        if (m.find())
        {   
           .... More code ...
        }
```

}

Example of file.getName() value: 
"1.0- 20190409095211_200522007_CNA_20180000959_1_xxxxx.pdf"

Apparently, m.find() is 'true' (so as Eclipse is showing me), but it never goes into inner if block, neither if I try to assign to another boolean value.

Tested in https://regex101.com/ and it get value.

My Java version is "1.8.0_181" 64-Bit server.

I'm newbie in StackOverflow, Java and Eclipse.

Comment: Please delete your Eclipse screen capture link and instead include all relevant Java code directly in the question.

Comment: Add your code in the question instead of the image

Comment: If you use `if (m.find()) { ... }` without calling `.find()` before it it must work if your regex matches the string.

Comment: You'll see better in the image, but I putting the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, where it shows `m.find()` as `true` and the same value assigned to `isMatch` variable to be `false`, meaning both are not in sync, and the only reason I can think of is, as you are in debug mode and since you have them in expression window, `m.find()` seems to be getting executed multiple times, where the first time value of `m.find()` must have been true, but as it got executed again, next time it didn't match the data and `m.find()'s` value became `false` and that ultimately got assigned to `isMatch` variable.

Try getting rid of debug mode and just run the code and the variable `isMatch`'s value should be in sync and should be as expected. Or you can even just turn off the expressions window while debugging your code, and debugging should give you correct values as expected. Make sure you don't re-evaluate `m.find()` else your program will give you unexpected results.

Also, never access `.group()` methods unless value returned by `m.find()` or `m.matches()` is `true`

For me, your code works fine like expected and prints `true`.

```
String REGEX_PATTERN_FILE_GROUP = "(\\d{14}_\\d{9}_\\D{3}_\\d{11}_)";

String s = "1.0- 20190409095211_200522007_CNA_20180000959_1_xxxxx.pdf";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN_FILE_GROUP);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean isMatch = m.find();
System.out.println("isMatch: " + isMatch);
if (isMatch) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints,

```
isMatch: true
20190409095211_200522007_CNA_20180000959_
```

Comment: Does it happen even if it is inside a synchronized method?

Comment: synchronized method won't matter here as all the variables you're dealing with are local within the method. Moreover, re-evaluate doesn't need to call whole method again by some other thread, so while keeping the method synchronized, you can re-evaluate the expression as many times you want.

Comment: Thnaks Sir. Problem seems to be as you indicated: "meaning both are not in sync, and the only reason I can think of is, as you are in debug mode and since you have them in expression window, m.find() seems to be getting executed multiple times,"... I was getting mad wondering what was not working.

Comment: Yes, I know that happens sometimes and it gets a little frustrating :) Glad I was able to clarify on that.

Answer (score 1):

the find() method tries to find the occurrence of a regex pattern within a given string. If multiple occurrences are found in the string, then the first call to find() will jump to the first occurrence. Thereafter, each subsequent call to the find() method will go to the next matching occurrence, one by one.